# Partition "X" does not start on physical sector boundary

Tags: linux, partition, fdisk

After rund fdisk -l in my terminal I got this error message to /dev/sda2 and /dev/sda5.

[image]

Than I run parte align optimal on this two partition with this error.

All partition now have the same parameters

[image]

Is this the best parameters for this disk?

Is this pushing down my disk performance?

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: yes, especially if you use SSD:http://lifehacker.com/5837769/make-sure-your-partitions-are-correctly-aligned-for-optimal-solid-state-drive-performance